# Circular Animation in Android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, android-animation

I want to create circular view with animation in **clockwise**.
I am able to achieve circular images with above code, but remaining with animation that will be going to happen after enable visibility of view.

```
totalViews: this is list of 10 views which is defined in XML
cardLogo: this is center white view.
```

[image: output]

[image: code snippet]

```
**UPDATE:**
 val angle = 360 / (totalViews.size)
        totalViews.onEachIndexed { i, view ->
            view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            totalCardViews[i].visibility = View.VISIBLE
            view.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                50.toPx(),
                50.toPx()
            ).apply {
                circleConstraint = R.id.cardLogo
                circleRadius = cardLogo.measuredWidth.div(2) + 40.toPx()// setting 40px away from white circle
                circleAngle = (i * angle).toFloat()
            }
            val path = Path().apply {
                arcTo(
                    50f,
                    cardLogo.width.div(2) - 90.toPx().toFloat(),
                    (cardLogo.height + 100.toPx()).toFloat(),
                    (cardLogo.width + 100.toPx()).toFloat(),
                    -90f,
                    (i * angle).toFloat(),
                    false
                )
            }
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.X, View.Y, path).setDuration(1500).start()
        }

//toPx() method to convert Int to Px
private fun Int.toPx(): Int =
    TypedValue.applyDimension(
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
        this.toFloat(), resources.displayMetrics
    ).toInt()
```

Comment: Please copypaste actual code instead of screenshot

Comment: @ChocolateChapta I've updated my Question, Please check once

Comment: check this example, it looks like exactly what you want http://www.tutorialsee.com/circle-menu/how-make-design-circle-menu-example-android